# Remove or unregister the fence in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, google-awareness

I am using the Awareness API and have created a fence like this:

```
AwarenessFence activityFence = DetectedActivityFence.during(DetectedActivityFence.STILL);
AwarenessFence headphoneFence = HeadphoneFence.during(HeadphoneState.PLUGGED_IN);

AwarenessFence stillWithHeadPhoneFence = AwarenessFence.and(activityFence, headphoneFence);

Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_FENCE);
                        PendingIntent fencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(((Activity) context), 0, intent, 0);

MyFenceReceiver mFenceBroadcastReceiver = new MyFenceReceiver();
                        ((Activity) context).registerReceiver(mFenceBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION_FENCE));

FenceUpdateRequest.Builder builder = new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder();
                        builder.addFence(Constants.IDLE_WITH_HEADPHONES_ON, stillWithHeadPhoneFence, fencePendingIntent);

Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(googleApiClient, builder.build());
```

And this is my broadcast receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(TextUtils.equals(Constants.ACTION_FENCE, intent.getAction())) {
            FenceState fenceState = FenceState.extract(intent);

            if( TextUtils.equals(Constants.IDLE_WITH_HEADPHONES_ON, fenceState.getFenceKey() ) ) {

                if( fenceState.getCurrentState() == FenceState.TRUE ) {
                    //
                }
            }


        }
```

The problem is that i need to unregister or remove the fence once the receiver executes for the first time. I am looking for ways to remove the fence and it requires an instance of GoogleApiClient. How can i get that instance in the receiver?

P.s: I can't call the remove in onStop cz the fence can be triggered even when the activity has been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Code ....

        context.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

};
```

Register :

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mReceiver, new IntentFilter(...));
```

Comment: if the broadcast receiver is itself unregistered, then it won'tbe able to listen to other fences. i only need that particular fence to be unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the fences which are executed/completed by adding fences with unique key, so that each and every fences have different fence key. Now to remove it, just call removeFence function with the unique key for the fence to be removed.

sample function is as given below:

```
private void unregisterFence(String unique_key) {
    Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                    .removeFence(unique_key)
                    .build()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Fence unregistered successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Cannot unregister fence.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```